# Convert a series of type string to type Date (not Datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a Date column whose content is: years-months-days of type string. I want to convert this to Date type (not Datetime). The goal is to insert this dataframe into a bigquery table with the Date type.

I tried:

```
df['Date '] = [datetime.strptime(str(i), '%Y-%m-%d') for i in df['Date ']]
```

But this still returns Datetime format Years-Months-Days Hours:Minutes:Seconds (2022-01-03 00:00:00)

Someone have an idea to convert this string to type Date:Y-m-d (not Datetime)

Comment: There is no date type, just datetime. Sometimes the display varies but this is always the same object. You should not worry about it and test your next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pandas.to_datetime() and extract the date:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dates':['2020-01-22', '2021-05-06', '2022-01-01']})
df.Dates.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date())
```

outputs:

```
0    2020-01-22
1    2021-05-06
2    2022-01-01
Name: Dates, dtype: object
```